# Best practice to inactivate records from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I Have two table in Database

1.ProductType
[image: Product Type]
2.Product
[image: Product]
User can set IsActive = *false* in  any  table.
I want user cannot set IsActive=*false* in ProductTypeTable if its ProductTypeID is Used in Product table.
what is the best practice.
I am working in asp.net MVC 4

Comment: Well, you can try to select all active products using this productCategory. If the query returns anything, it means you shouldn't disable this category. Or you could also "cascade" disable the products, it depends on your requirements. That said this is typically not a question for SO as it's opinion-based and it's not code-related as such

Answer (score 0):

Try create a constructor method in your model and set the value of attribute to false, like this:

```
 public class ProductType
    {
        public ProductType()
        {
           IsActive = false;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

When you instance the class, always is false, but you can set after too. In your Create method, don't set attribute isActive